# Local gem install vs running setup.rb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What is the difference between a ruby library installed from a tarball versus through a gem install?

My machine can't connect to rubygems.org because of a university proxy, so all my installations happen locally. I have some gems that I've installed using a gem local install, and others where I've downloaded a tarball and run setup.rb or some such. In my newbie-ish state when messing around with Ruby I wasn't too phased about this inconsistency, but it bothers me now.

I assume rubygems is the preferred method, but I'd like to understand the exact pitfalls so that I can know what to watch out for when I try clean out my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important difference is that Ruby extensions installed without the gem mechanism cannot be easily uninstalled or updated (except they provide their own mechanism for that). Automatic installation of dependencies is also largely simplified with gems.

If you are behind a proxy, you can tell `gem` to use that proxy as well, e.g.

```
gem install foo --http-proxy http://192.168.0.1:81
```

or define the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` like

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:81
```

Look into your browser/network settings to find the proxy address.

Comment: Hah, if only so easy on the proxy front. I've gone as far as using CNTLM to create a local proxy that passes the credentials properly. No such luck :/.

Comment: @FritzMeissner: I'm sorry for that.